# How to do LIKE comparison on INT column in OrmLite?

Tags: sql-server, int, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, sql-like

I want to do sql `LIKE` comparison on `INT` column using ServiceStack.OrmLite. Basically I need OrmLite to generate the following sql where clause:

`where intColumn like '%123%'`

I know I can use `.Contains()` on `strings` but my property/column is `int`.
Also using `.ToString().Contains()` on `int` property is throwing the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitColumnAccessMethod(MethodCallExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitColumnAccessMethod(MethodCallExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.AppendToWhere(String condition, Expression predicate)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Where(Expression`1 predicate)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Where CAST(intColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) like '%123%'`

Comment: @M.Ali I modified the question to be more clear. I need to do this using OrmLite not SQL itself. In sql server `where intColumn like '%123%'` would just work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to append a custom SQL Where condition:

```
 var results = db.From<Table>(q => q.Where("intColumn like '%123%'"));
```

Comment: I really want to stay away from custom SQL. I think it would be nice to have this feature implemented. Do you think it is likely :) ?

Comment: By new feature I mean the `casting` feature such that it would translate `q.Where(x => x.IntColumn.ToString().Contains("123"))` to `where cast(intColumn as varchar) like '%123%'`.

Comment: @kaptan It's unlikely SqlExpressions will be refactored to support this: it's obscure (never seen/used), it's usage and what SQL it should generate is non-obvious. Basically a classic case for a custom SQL condition. Another option is to wrap this behind your own type SqlExpression Extension method that delegates to `q.Where(sql)` underneath.

Comment: I think casting to string feature can be useful in many use cases. One being the one I mentioned. NHibernate has it since four years ago ver 3.2 https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2563. I think OrmLite users will be very happy to have this feature :)

Comment: @kaptan Having the right side of the expression be able to create an explicit cast for the left side of the expression could cause a lot of unforeseen breaking changes for very little value, i.e. something to be avoided. If anything the expression and cast would need to be explicit. But this isn't feature that has been requested yet, you [could add it as a feature request here](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).